# Why are state transition storyboards forcing "Hold In" easing for a listbox?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation, expression-blend

I am trying to use the Visual State Manager in blend to animate a state transition.  For simple state transitions where I do not have a multi-control, multi-key storyboard things seem to work.  When I try to implement a complex storyboard as part of a state transition I am having trouble.

I have a listbox that I am trying to animate movement on a canvas.  When I move it using the Blend designer it registers the animation, but the easing for the move is set to "Hold In" and I can not change it.  This seems to be making a DiscreteObjectKeyFrame animation, while I believe I want a double animation, but I'm not sure how to make blend do what I want here.  Animating opacity seems to work as expected.

How do I animate the listbox's position on the canvas with a linear easing?

Comment: When you say animate movement on a canvas, what effect do you mean exactly? Are you trying to animate the listbox position within the boundary of a canvas control? Or are you looking to just do something that might be as easily remedied as setting easing on a fluidmovebehavior for say a wrappanel to move objects for width/height requirements? Basically what effect are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The former - trying to move the listbox position within the boundary of a canvas control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by trying to animate a property that only supports discrete frame animation.  To get this to work, you have to use a custom path for the animation or pick another property (preferably of type double) that supports smooth animation.